# Bounding number of k-cycles in a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, cycles

Fix any $k \geq 3$, and suppose I have a simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$. I want a bound on the number of $k$ cycles in $G$ as a function of $|E|$. In particular, I would like to prove the following "conjectured" statement:

**W.T.S:** Given any $G=(V,E)$, the number of $k$-cycles in $G$ is at most $O(|E|^{k/2})$.

Clearly $\binom{|V|}{k}$ is tight if we only wanted a bound in terms of $|V|$, which comes from the complete graph on $|V|$ vertices. However, it is not as clear how to prove a tight upper bound in terms of $|E|$. The intuition for the conjecture is that, up to a constant, it seems that it should be optimal to arrange your edges in a complete graph (if $k$ is even, you do win a constant by taking a complete bipartite graph instead of a complete graph).

There seem to be a few proofs of this fact for triangles (k=3), for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823481/number-of-triangles-in-a-graph-based-on-number-of-edges. However, they don't generalize in any clear way to larger $k$. Moreover, I don't know of any k-cycle enumeration algorithms for k>3 that are parameterized by $|E|$ (the runtime of which would provide an upper bound).

For my application I actually only need bounds for odd $k$, but it seems that any such proof should generalize to any $k$. Also, to be clear, I'm only interested in asymtotic bounds here in terms of $|E|$ (getting tight constants seem much more difficult). Any suggestions or references that I missed would be much appreciated.

Comment: For $k=4$ the appropriate complete graph has nearly twice as many $k$-cycles as the complete bipartite graph, not that that changes things. For example $K_{50}$ and $K_{35,35}$ and  each have $|E|=1225$ but the first has $690900$  $4$-cycles and the latter has $354025.$ The same should be true for larger ever $k$ as well.

Comment: Ooops, right you are. I miscounted the number of 4 cycles in the complete graph, I forgot that four vertices give rise to multiple 4-cycles. Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is addressed in the paper:

*Rivin, Igor*, [**Counting cycles and finite dimensional (L^{p}) norms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0196-8858(02)00037-4), Adv. Appl. Math. 29, No. 4, 647-662 (2002). [ZBL1013.05042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1013.05042).

Comment: Incredible -- I had a feeling that bounding Tr(A^k) would be a good approach, but I didn't see how to do it. The fact that Tr(A^2) = |E| is a great catch. Thanks for the beautiful proof!

Comment: @RajeshJayaram Thanks for the kind words!